# Generating O(N^2) without loops

Tags: c#, big-o

I understand you can generate an O(N^2) algorithm by using loops:

eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        //do something N^2 times.
    }
}
```

Is it possible to generate an O(N^2) without using loops (for, foreach, while, goto)?
How would you do it?

Comment: Recursion.  Some kind of naive version of merge sort could be O(n^2) without a double loop.  There is probably some kind of recursive algorithm that is n^2 without using any loops but I can't think of an example which isn't completely inane.

Comment: I believe it's up to your circumstance. Some cases have to use O(n^2) for the solution, I work on sync lot of data between 2 systems and it's use loop in loop alot (have to upgrade RAM 64GB and 1000GB SDD). For general, it you want to break and O(n^2), the case must have a special point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [General way to convert a loop (while/for) to recursion or from a recursion to a loop?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/279004/general-way-to-convert-a-loop-while-for-to-recursion-or-from-a-recursion-to-a)

Comment: What do you mean by "loops"?

Comment: Voting to re-open this. Just because @thomas-owens et al find it unclear, does not make it an unclear question. This is made clear by the two, good quality, answers.

Comment: @DavidArno: Eh, it's "explaining code," which is still off-topic here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I disagree. It uses code to explain the principles, but it is about real software engineering ideas around O(N^2) and loops, not how to write code to achieve it.

Comment: How is it unclear what I'm asking? I want to know how to generate an O(N^2) without using loops (any loops in C#).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a somewhat contrived example, squaring a number using recursion and no loops.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var num_to_square = 10;
        Console.WriteLine(square(num_to_square)); //100
    }

    public static int square(int n)
    {
        return recurse(n-1, n-1);
    }

    private static int recurse(int x, int y)
    {
        int c = 1;
        if (x + y == 0)
        {
            return c;
        }

        c += recurse(x - 1, y);
        if (x == y)
        {
            c += recurse(x - 1, y - 1);
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**No.***  Any algorithm with no loops must be `O(1)`, because you know at compile-time how many steps the algorithm will take (at most).

Unless by "using a loop" you mean actually writing one of the C# iteration statements: `for`, `foreach`, `do`, or `while`.  Then of course there are other ways, but I'd argue they're all just different ways of making a loop.  For instance:

```
i = 0;
Outer:
    j = 0;
    Inner:
        //do something N^2 times.
        j++;
        if (j < N) {
            goto Inner;
        }
    i++;
    if (i < N) {
        goto Outer;
    }
```

That's your same loop written with `goto`.  Or how about this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, N).SelectMany(i =>
    Enumerable.Range(0, N).Select(j => { /*do something N^2 times*/ })
).ToList();
```

There's the same loop using `Enumerable` methods and extensions.  Does it count if the implementation of `ToList` uses a loop?

***Depending on how you count recursion**

There's certainly an argument to be made that recursion is just plain "different" from iteration, but [every recursive algorithm can be converted into an equivalent iterative one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931762/can-every-recursion-be-converted-into-iteration)  In fact it would be perfectly reasonable for a compiler to do this.  Does your algorithm "use a loop" if it is logically equivalent to an algorithm which uses a loop?  It just depends on exactly what you mean by "algorithm".

Comment: Wouldn't it be O(N) because in the worst case, you could get N from user input?

Comment: @Backwards_Dave Wouldn't what be `O(N)`?  An algorithm with no loops?  No, it must be `O(1)`.  To see why, write the execution steps of the algorithm as a directed graph.  A loop is a cycle in the graph.  With no cycles, there is a finite-length longest possible path through the graph, and no input can make it longer.